# How to find the 10 foods with the highest Protein per Calorie?

Tags: data

```
foodToVitCData = EntityClass["Food",
   {
    EntityProperty["Food", "Preparation"] -> Entity["FoodPreparation", "Raw"],
    EntityProperty["Food", "RelativeTotalProteinContent"] -> TakeLargest[10]
   }
][{"RelativeTotalProteinContent"}, "EntityPropertyAssociation"]
```

will give me the 10 with the highest relative total protein content, but how to construct a compound criterion RelativeTotalProteinContent/RelativeTotalCaloriesContent?

Comment: I believe [`EntityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityFunction.html) is what you need. Can you please try `EntityClass["Food", {EntityProperty["Food", "Preparation"] -> Entity["FoodPreparation", "Raw"], EntityFunction[c, c["RelativeTotalCaloriesContent"]] -> TakeLargest[10]}][{"RelativeTotalProteinContent"}, "EntityPropertyAssociation"]`? However, it looks like this downloads the whole database first, which is probably not what you want, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if the result here is correct, so there may be an error in my approach, but I think you can do something along these lines...

First, create a new entity class by extending the food class:

```
newClass = 
  ExtendedEntityClass[
    EntityClass[
      "Food",
      {EntityProperty["Food", "Preparation"] -> Entity["FoodPreparation", "Raw"]}],
      "ProteinPerCalorie" -> EntityFunction[c, c["RelativeTotalProteinContent"]/c["RelativeTotalCaloriesContent"]]]
```

Now sort and select your desired items:

```
EntityList[SortedEntityClass[newClass, "ProteinPerCalorie" -> "Descending", 10]]
(* The results by "Name" property are
  {"Coconut Secret Raw Coconut Vinegar", "Columbus, Sopressata", <7>>, "Emu, outside drum, raw"}
*)
```